# Losing server that generated CSR (Certificate Signing Request)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate

I have created a CSR file on a Windows server about 3 months earlier and used this CSR file to buy a wildcard SSL Certificate. The SSL company (opentrust) then gave me 3 files, the root CA file, the intermediate and the wildcard certificate. But I suddenly lost the server that the CSR file had been created on, so I can't complete the process of SSL certificate request. The weird thing is I imported these 3 files in certificate store of 4 of my Windows servers and when I open the certificate on each of these servers, it shows that a corresponding private key is present although the DNS names of these servers do not match the certificate, but on the other servers there is no private key.

I don't know why this happens and if I recreate the CSR file, the SSL company will charge me again for reissuing the certificate or not.